# Find 95% confidence intervals from grouped dataset

Tags: confidence-interval

I have got the following dataset, which comes from a Normal Distribution, and that can be grouped by 3 months in total and the monthly observations are the ones that interest me:

```
Date          Height  
01-01-1990    120
01-01-1990    187
01-01-1990    113
01-02-1990    154
01-02-1990    160
01-02-1990    167
01-03-1990    137
01-03-1990    190
01-03-1990    159
```

I need to find the 95% confidence intervals and I was wondering if I can use all the dataset in order to calculate the `mean`, `standard deviation` and `size` of the sample population OR if by doing so I will create biases in the output.

**1)**
The possible outcome, by considering all the observations singularly, would be:

```
Mean of Height = 154.1111
Standard deviation of Height = 26.78826
Size of Height = 9

Error of Height = 17.50134

Low 95% C.I. = 154.1111 - 17.50134 = 136.6098
High 95% C.I. = 154.1111 + 17.50134 = 171.6125
```

**2)**
Another possibility that I was thinking is to compute the Height mean for each month (3 values in total) and use them as input to calculate the C.I., as follows:

```
x = Height mean for 01-01-1990 = 140.0000
y = Height mean for 01-02-1990 = 160.3333
z = Height mean for 01-03-1990 = 162.0000

Mean of Height = mean of x, y, z = 154.1111
Standard deviation of Height = sd of x, y, z = 12.24896
Size of Height = 3

Error of Height = 13.86075

Low 95% C.I. = 154.1111 - 13.86075 = 140.2504
High 95% C.I. = 154.1111 + 13.86075 = 167.9719
```

**Which of the two calculations is correct?
Or there exist any better way to calculate these C.I.?**

Thanks

######    UPDATE

What if I have got a dataset with only multiple observations in the same month (and year)?

e.g.

```
Date          Height  
01-01-1990    120
01-01-1990    187
01-01-1990    113
01-01-1990    154
01-01-1990    160
01-01-1990    167
01-01-1990    137
01-01-1990    190
01-01-1990    159
```

Assuming that I want to remain consistent, in the analysis, with the previous dataset (3 months), how can I calculate my C.I. now, assuming that I desire a sample size = 1 (because only one month exists in the dataset)?

If I apply the stratified version as **2)** my standard deviation will be = NA and therefore I cannot calculate the C.I. as per the other dataset.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer will depend on how you interpret values coming from the same month.

**Independent Version**

What if every value is a sample spaced 10 days? Then your month indications are relatively meaningless. Crossing the month barrier does not matter and you should lump all of the data together independent of months. You've already done that in your first equation.

**Stratified Version**

Month matters here in some way to cause values to cluster together or it's in some way a meaningful grouping variable. In this case you might use your second calculation. What you're doing is averaging the values within a month together in order to get a better estimate for a particular month. It will likely reduce your between month variability and make your estimate not about the mean value per se but about the mean value expected for any month.

**Your Update**

A CI based on your final example will mean a different thing. Without multiple months the CI can't generalize across months and can only say something about January but not months in general. I will be a CI for January or Januaries. You could try to extrapolate it to other months but it wouldn't be as strong inferentially as either of the other CIs calculated using data from multiple months.

As you keep developing examples and trying to test things remember that you need to think about interpretation and what things can mean as much as the calculations.

(BTW, there are other ways to deal with the averaging more explicitly in multi-level modelling which you might want to read up on for more advanced data problems like this)

Comment: Hi John and thanks. I am interested in the stratified version you mentioned but I need the overall (3 months) C.I.. Is it possible to know the steps to follow in order to calculate them?

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: you just deleted it!!! :)

Comment: thanks @John. I updated my question with an extra question and I have also this awaiting an answer http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247710/test-statistical-significance-with-confidence-intervals-example-needed . I will wait a couple of days before mark the best answers. Thanks

Comment: Hi @John. so how can I calculate the CI for my update question by remaining consistent with the Stratified version? you didn't specify this in your answer..

Comment: Magic? How could you expect to have the same generalizability when you only have data from one month? It's not really a matter of how you do the calculation but what the result means.